# Запуск программы свернутой в трей

Tags: c#, winforms

Как организовать запуск программы сразу свернутой в трей?
Делал сворачивание по нажатию на кнопку "Свернуть":

```
private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Show();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
}

private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        this.Hide();
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

А как организовать, чтобы приложение сразу при запуске появлялось в трее, без показа формы на экране?

Comment: Ни разу не дубликат - там речь шла о запуске чужой программы, здесь же речь идет о своей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого главным образом нужно вызывать `Application.Run()`, не передавая в него форму в качестве параметра.

Если хотите иметь в трее иконку, модифицируйте метод `Main` следующим образом (контекстное меню опционально):

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var form = new Form1();

    using (NotifyIcon icon = new NotifyIcon())
    {
        icon.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Application.ExecutablePath);
        icon.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(
            new []
            {
                new MenuItem("Show form", (s, e) => form.Show()),
                new MenuItem("Hide form", (s, e) => form.Hide()),
                new MenuItem("Exit", (s, e) => Application.Exit()),
            });
        icon.Visible = true;

        Application.Run();
        icon.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1617821/1985167)

Answer (score 1):

Сворачивайте окно в обработчике загрузки формы.

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    this.Hide();
}
```